# Подпись у кнопки

Tags: html

Всем привет

```
echo "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"key\" value=\"\">
</form>";
```

Есть форма внутри кода PHP (она ест-но больше). При наведении на input хотел сделать так:

```
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"key\" value=\"\" title=\"превед!!1\">
```

т.е. что бы внизу была подпись к кнопке. Ничего не получилось. Подскажите как быть?

p.s. в опере - нет (огнелис - да)

Comment: Странно, у меня все получилось...

--------------------------------

З.Ы. в опере - да

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" class="key" value="" title="превед!!1">
```

данный код полностью рабочий (проверял в 3 браузерах). При наведении мышки на данную кнопку всплывает подсказка.